# Safari in kiosk mode or full screen with no tool bars

Tags: safari, fullscreen, html5-video, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I have created a html5 video gallery that will be used as a kiosk in a casino. The videos play the best in safari but I cannot get safari to go completely full screen. Is there a way to do this or a application I can use? I've looked into saft but it is not compatible with the new version of safari.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://robnyman.github.com/fullscreen/

Answer (score 0):

At least on Windows version of Safari (5.1.7), To make it go full-screen you have to press F11.

You will still see a tool-bar, but it should automatically hide after a few seconds, and then you will be in complete full-screen mode.

Note: If you press F11 before all the content of your page are loaded, you might have some layout problems, so I recommend to wait for the content to be loaded.

I wish there was a way to make full-screen mode enabled from start up like you can do with Google Chrome with the kiosk mode, but I don't know if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a third-party kiosk application designed for this purpose such as [xStand](http://www.xstandapp.com/en/index.html), since Safari doesn't contain any actual kiosk mode (unlike Internet Explorer).

Even then, you'll need to be aware of the risk of users using keyboard shortcuts to exit the application (like <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd> to bring up the "Force Quit Applications" list).

Most dedicated kiosk browsers are designed to disallow that sort of behaviour, but you should definitely test them yourself before you trust them (or disconnect the keyboard altogether if users don't need a keyboard).

On the other hand, if you can safely remove the keyboard and mouse, you're able to simply use the built-in full-screen mode in Safari (as of OS X Lion), to achieve what you're looking for.